# Passing space as a parameter

Tags: c, parameter-passing, whitespace

When Passing space as a parameter can it be passed in using `' '`?
I'm currently recreating `printf`.

The code below is an example of what I am passing in.

When it's passed in like this it works fine:

```
ft_printf("Start %-+# 0400.500hhiend\n");
```

This leads be to believe that space can not be passed in as a parameter like this `' '`, but I just want to double check.

Passing it in:

```
ft_printf("Start %-+#' '0400.500hhiend\n");
```

Parsing code:

```
while (fmt[count] == '-' || fmt[count] == '+' || fmt[count] == ' ' ||
       fmt[count] == '#' || fmt[count] == '0')
```

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing the definition of `ft_printf`. If you include `' '` within `"...' '..."` you are just including the three literal characters `' '` within the string itself. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In POSIX [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), the apostrophe `'` is a valid format modifier, meaning use the thousands grouping character (the `thousands_sep` in `struct lconv` from `<locale.h>`).  Repeating it is unnecessary, but probably not harmful.  The numeric part of the format doesn't make as much sense; the `0` means leading zeros (but you also have `-` for left justified; the `400` minimum width is ridiculously wide; the `.500` minimum number of digits is normally is smaller than the `400`; `hhi` means (signed) character value.  Odd!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback so far!

Let's ignore the fact I am recreating printf.
I think this may be misleading my core question.

"Is ' ' equivalent to just passing a space as a parameter to a function?

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot. Printf parses the string by analyzing what is between the percent sign and the final and inevitable type conversion (i.e "diouxXcspf").

I suppose you could always parse the string in a more efficient manner by having a list of symbols (generated using a rudimentary lexer) that represent the different flags and such and calling different functions depending on what they are, which would prevent having to "pass spaces as arguments".